# Regex Find email address between First Two Instances of Strings

Tags: python, regex, string, text, python-re

I have raw text from a chain of emails.

```
For all inquiries please reach out
From: abc@abc.com At: 01/27/21 23:29:28To: CompanyA
Cc: 123@123.com, 345@345-YYY.com Subject: this is the subject line
From: CompanyB(company) <mmm@mmm.net>
Sent: Wednesday, January 27, 2021 12:51 PM
From: 999@999.com At: 01/27/21 23:29:28To: CompanyA
Cc: 888@888.com, 777@777.com Subject: tect
```

Through Regex I need to capture the email addresses between the first word **From** to the first **Subject**.  In the above the match should be:
abc@abc.com
123@123.com
345@345-YYY.com

I do have **(\n){0,1}([\w.]*@[\w+-.]*)** to get email addresses. I will match through Python Regex Lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use 2 patterns with re.

First find all the matches from `From:` till the first occurrence of `Subject:`

```
(?s)\bFrom:.*?\bSubject:
```

Then for all those matches, get the email address like patterns without matching `<` and `>`

```
[^<>\s@]+@[^@\s<>]+
```

Example

```
import re
s = ("For all inquiries please reach out\n"
            "From: abc@abc.com At: 01/27/21 23:29:28To: CompanyA\n"
            "Cc: 123@123.com, 345@345-YYY.com Subject: this is the subject line\n"
            "From: CompanyB(company) <mmm@mmm.net>\n"
            "Sent: Wednesday, January 27, 2021 12:51 PM\n"
            "From: 999@999.com At: 01/27/21 23:29:28To: CompanyA\n"
            "Cc: 888@888.com, 777@777.com Subject: tect")

for match in re.findall(r"(?s)\bFrom:.*?\bSubject:", s):
        print(re.findall(r"[^<>\s@]+@[^@\s<>]+", match))
```

Output

```
['abc@abc.com', '123@123.com,', '345@345-YYY.com']
['mmm@mmm.net', '999@999.com', '888@888.com,', '777@777.com']
```

---

If you don't want to cross another occurrence of `From:` or `Subject`, you can use a negative lookahead to check if the line does not contain any of the strings.

```
^From:.*(?:\r?\n(?!From|.*\bSubject:).*)*\r?\n.*\bSubject:
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mgnxGc/1)

Example

```
for match in re.findall(r"(?m)^From:.*(?:\r?\n(?!From|.*\bSubject:).*)*\r?\n.*\bSubject:", s):
        print(re.findall(r"[^<>\s@]+@[^@\s<>]+", match))
```

Output

```
['abc@abc.com', '123@123.com,', '345@345-YYY.com']
['999@999.com', '888@888.com,', '777@777.com']
```